# Artifactory Failed to update repository - Repository aggregates another repository that has a mismatching package type

Tags: artifactory

I have a virtual repository in Artifactory that comprises of a few repositories of different repo types.

When I try to add in a Maven repository into the virtual repository it throws an error saying "Failed to update repository" and in the logs states :

```
2016-03-29 17:15:50,814 [http-nio-8082-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.u.r.s.a.c.r.UpdateRepositoryConfigService:43) - Updating repository MyCompany-dev
2016-03-29 17:15:50,814 [http-nio-8082-exec-16] [ERROR] (o.a.u.r.s.a.c.r.UpdateRepositoryConfigService:48) - Failed to update repository MyCompany-dev: Repository 'MyCompany-dev' aggregates another repository 'org.python.pypi' that has a mismatching package type Pypi
```

We are running version :

Artifactory Professional 4.5.1 rev 40117

The artifactory website suggests that

"Combining and chaining repositories that use different layouts should work out-of-the-box."

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts

So I'm not sure why it's throwing an error suggesting it can't add a maven repository to the virtual repo because there is a pypi repo already in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing layouts with package types - aggregating several different layouts into one virtual repository is supported as you mentioned, but it's not possible to aggregate several different **package types** into one virtual repository of a certain type (in your case - a Pypi virtual repository cannot contain Maven repositories or any other type except for Pypi).

See more [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-SinglePackageType) and [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-SinglePackageTypeRepositories).